# How to count sum for different records in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

I have a table of 10 questions and answers in DB. (:question_id, :answer)

1,3,5,7,9 questions are group 1.

2,4,6,8,10 questions are group 2.

Each question has 2 answers:A/B.

A= 0

B= 1

I need to count sum for answers to questions in each group.
How to do this?

Comment: You want the number of questions in each group, or the sum of the answers (with A = 0, B = 1) to questions in each group? Please clarify.

Comment: my mistake,thanks! I need to count sum for answers to questions in each group. Also i don't have specific groups in my table, only :question_id and :answer.

Comment: Why do you have `question_id` when your model is called `Question`? You don't need to assign an id to the record itself, it has an id by default.

Comment: Because every visitor must be able to choose answers for these 10 questions.

Comment: So what? You already have an `id` for each question, you don't need another one. Maybe you need a question id on your `User` model, but that's different. I think you should review the rails docs, you seem to be a bit confused about the basics.

Comment: User has_many Questions? Well, maybe it should be called Answers and has only one column :answer:integer? So in this case, how to count sum for two different groups? Should it create special columnt "groups" or not? How?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Question.count(:group => 'group_id')
```

assuming you have a Activerecord model called Question and it has a column attribute called group_id to keep groups

HTH

Comment: Thanks but how create this column attribute (group_id)? I don't have it. I used 'rails g scaffold Question question_id:integer answer:integer'

Comment: I believe you are having a group_id column in questions table to identify which question is belongs to which group! :)

Comment: I made groupd_id column, but Question.count(:group => 'group_id') doesn't show sum. How to show sum for example Group 1?

Comment: as far as I remember, this will give you the key and the count, as an example if you have an id as 1 and sum as 4, then it gives u [1,5]. So after that you might need to figure out a way to identify the ids :)